# jQuery UI custom build - how do I find out which components are included?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have two jQuery UI custom builds; they were made by different people from different versions of the code (1.8.9 vs. 1.8.11). The file sizes differ by 50k, so obviously different components are included in each. Is there a command/script I can run that will list the included components for each one ? I'm trying to create a single new build to replace both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of.  You can grab the names under the $.ui and compare them together.

```
var names = [];
for(name in $.ui)
   names.push(name);
```

It'll grab a bunch of other methods too, but it'll get you the names of installed plugins.

Answer (score 2):

This would pretty simple to ascertain manually without using a command line tool or script.  All the widgets used in a build have a big block comment in the outputted file.  Here's Draggable from version 1.8.9:

```
;/*
* jQuery UI Draggable 1.8.9 
* 
* Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about) 
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses. 
* http://jquery.org/license 
* 
* http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggables 
* 
* Depends: 
*    jquery.ui.core.js 
*    jquery.ui.mouse.js 
*    jquery.ui.widget.js 
*/
```

Should be as easy as going through each file, noting which comments you have and comparing for differences.

Comment: This does work, even on minified files, but is more work than the code solution.